# Electromagnetic brake torque control

Tags: control, torque

I'm looking for ways to control the holding torque on an axis for force feedback purposes. I stumbled upon electromagnetic brakes which might be useful for this. But i'm not sure to what extent you are able to control the holding torque of a electromagnetic brake, maybe its just a on/off kind of thing.

So can you control the holding torque of an electromagnetic brake by for instance pwm the voltage on the coil?

i'm looking for the model on page 420: http://sriramalenze.com/download/lenze%20Clutches11.pdf

Comment: do you have a link to the device?

Comment: I'm sorry, that would have been usefull. 

It is the model on page 420 i'd like to order:
http://sriramalenze.com/download/lenze%20Clutches11.pdf

Comment: I don't think it can be used the way you asked but why not call them.

Answer (score 2):

The device mentioned uses an electromagnet to attract a rotating armature plate inward. Removing the coil power releases the armature to be pulled back by springs.

Thus, using PWM on the coil will provide a graduated braking torque.

Points to keep in mind:

- Too low a PWM frequency will cause perceptible shudder
- IF the PWM frequency is a harmonic of the rotation rate, resonance will occur, with detrimental effects.

PWM-based electromagnetic actuation such as in this case can be done with a **spread-spectrum PWM signal**, i.e. one where the PWM base frequency varies cycle by cycle, often using a pseudorandom sequence.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but just got the component and it's fully functioning. So you were right.